# NULL property value for a custom Personalization Condition

Tags: sitecore, rule-engine, sitecore8, personalization

I need to create a custom Condition for Personalization to check if a specific time has passed (without date).
So I created the new class as following:

```
public class TimePassedCondition<T> : Sitecore.Rules.Conditions.OperatorCondition<T> where T : RuleContext
{
     public string SelectedTime { get; set; }

     protected override bool Execute(T ruleContext)
     {
        //TODO: Add Logic
        return false;
    }
}
```

Then I added a new Condition definition in

`Sitecore/System/Settings/Rules/Elements/Date/`
and i gave it the following Text:
`when [SelectedTime,DateTime,,the time] has passed`
I also added the new Personalization Condition and Action to the required component.
So when I debug and open the page, the break points gets hit.

However, my problem is that according to what I read in several articles, the `SelectedTime` property should be filled with the datetime selected when I created the Personalization Condition, but it is always NULL for me.

What am I missing?

Note: this is Sitecore 8.1

Comment: have you tried declaring SelectedTime as a DateTime in your condition?

Comment: Yes. I get the default value: `"1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM"`

Comment: I looks about right. Are you sure you have set and published a date time on the instance of the condition you are testing?

Comment: Did you modify the condition after setting up some inital personalization? Completely clear out the personalization setup,  rebuild it, and publish.

Comment: Damn it..... Thanks @JimNoellsch. I cleared and rebuilt the conditions and it worked. Add your solution below please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Completely clear out the personalization conditions and rebuild them.

Personalization is stored as XML in a `<condition>` element with attribute names that mirror your storage variable name. This is problematic if you refactor the underlying storage variable in the rule text - they don't stay in sync and won't be mapped when the rule is run.